# Best means of transport in Switzerland for two days

Tags: switzerland, jungfrau-region

I will be visiting Switzerland on July 13 and 14, 2019. My plan is to stay with my friend at Martigni and cover Jungfraujoch on 13th and lakes brienz, thun, giessbach falls on 14th.

I would be arriving in Geneva on the night of July 12th from where I would be heading to my friend's place directly. I would be traveling to Zurich to catch a train to Munich on the evening of July 14, thus ending my stay in Switzerland.

Can someone please suggest what would be the best option to plan my travel inside Switzerland for the two days, taking into account that I will be visiting Jungfraujoch? Would the Swiss travel pass be the best option, or would buying point to point tickets work better? I have read that the Swiss travel pass would also let me do the lake cruises for free.

Any suggestions would be very much welcome. Also, if I can get a rough estimate of how much it would cost me for the two days I am there, it would be very helpful. Regarding meals, I am a vegetarian, and would be spending only for lunch on both the days.

Comment: Questions that ask for rough estimates are opinion based because it depends on your personal preference. IMO you should rephrase the last paragraph or this question may be closed.

Answer (score 3):

The minimum period for a Swiss Rail Pass is 3 days. I do believe you will make that back on you itinerary, if you include the lake cruises and the Jungfraujoch, which [appears](http://file:///C:/Users/alazarus/Downloads/uebersichtskarte-sts.pdf) to be only a 25% reduction, not free. That link has the full map of covered lines.

The pass also admits you to most museums, on the off-chance you are inside for more than a few minutes of this itinerary.

Answer (score 3):

If you are less than 26 years of age, you can buy 3 day [youth travel pass](https://www.sbb.ch/en/leisure-holidays/travel-in-switzerland/international-guests/swiss-travel-pass.html) for 198CHF (rather than 232CHF for adult pass). The pass allows you free lake rides, free local transport, free travel on normal trains and postbuses and free or reduced entry to most museums. The savings on mountain rail and cable cars range from 25-50%. You can check [the map](https://www.sbb.ch/content/dam/internet/sbb/en/infotexte/uebersichtskarte-sts.pdf.sbbdownload.pdf)

The pass will cover your travel from the moment you arrive in Geneva till you depart Zurich (You may have to buy it in advance because Geneva/Airport counters may not be manned if you arrive at night). Depending on your plan you can check point to point ticket cost (even for boats) on [SBB website](http://sbb.ch/en) and compare costs. But IMO travel pass will be cheaper (especially if you are eligible for youth pass).

An added advantage of pass is that you can be flexible in your plan. You reach Interlaken and find you don't have much time for the mountain. Just take the train to lauterbrunnen and cable care to murren to enjoy scenery for free!

Also you can include places that offer more savings to make your money back. Maybe go to Zermatt (50% off on Gornergrat rail and matterhorn glacier paradise and both together are cheaper than jungrafu) rather than Jungfraujoch. You can drop Thun lake ride to squeeze in a visit to Luzern (through beautiful golden pass brienz-luzern line after the must do interlaken brienz boat ride) while on your way to Zurich.

Comment: Thank you so much for these suggestions. I turned 27 just last month, so I will not be eligible to buy the youth travel pass. Nonetheless, I will check the prices of the point to point tickets and see whether buying a pass would save me more money. Thanks a lot for the suggestions once again. :)